# Anyone had this issue with Xcode? it keeps crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

So this is what I've encountered while coding in Xcode. Whatever I do I can't get rid of it and it won't allow me to move on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: This is what I get now in Xcode and can't get rid of it...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off, I noticed that the 'Parent Process' is `launchd_sim`. Then, the 'Responsible Process' is `SimulatorTrampoline`.

Thus, the crash source is likely to be the Simulator.

If this is indeed the case, try to switch your launch simulator. (E.G. from iPhone 13 Pro to iPhone 13.) If the issue persists, try to *entirely* kill all Xcode processes as well as Simulator processes. Reboot your computer, and re-launch. If the issue **still** persists, try creating a new simulator (File > New Simulator) from the Simulator menu.

If all else fails, invalidate the Xcode caches, erase all the data on the simulator (Device > Erase All Content and Settings). Perhaps try uninstalling Xcode as an ***ultimate*** last resort.

Cheers, and hope the problem gets solved soon.

Comment: Well I've tried most of the things you pointed out before I posted this issue here. Then I've noticed that an update showed up so I've done it and for now it's working. Hopefully it will be ok now.